# Finding the type of UI element in a userform

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a user login form which has textboxes, dropdowns etc . I want to list down the type of elements i.e. textboxes and dropdowns in an xml document which I am using as a database.

Is there any c# namespace and functions to get the ui element type and store it in the xml document.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please show your work also? Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Atleast show us where you're in code and well guide from there.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yt340bh4(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: There's reflection to inspect objects such as ui elements at runtime, and there are multiple options to save data as xml - but there isn't a one-liner to answer your question with. You should probably try to solve the problem piece by piece. There are tons of reflection tutorials online you could google, to start with.